# Perl: fastest way to count with big data (300million+ lines)

Tags: perl, loops, count

I have a dataset:

```
domain,ip,org
emileaben.com, 94.31.44.1, Level 3 Communications
anaplan.com, 94.31.44.12, Level 3 Communications
anaplan.com, 94.31.44.15, abc
anaplan.com, 94.31.44.19, Level 3 Communications
```

and I would like to count number of ips per domain per organization which would give me this result:

```
domain,countip,org
anaplan.com, 2, Level 3 Communications
emileaben.com, 1, Level 3 Communications
anaplan.com, 1, abc
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: As a one off thing? If not this is what databases are for

Comment: Have you tried something that was too slow?

Comment: No I have not tried with Perl actually , I do not know perl that well, just a beginner. I tried with python at it is very slow

Comment: @UserYmY can you quantify slow? I imagine there will not be that large of a difference in performance for a reasonable solution in Perl vs Python; the issue is probably with your implementation.

Comment: Can you show us the Python code that was too slow?  Maybe we can help speed that up rather than writing it over.  It usually makes more sense to modify existing working code than to start over from scratch.

Comment: Are the rows in your input file sorted such that domains are always grouped together?

Answer (score 3):

From command line, no sorting,

```
perl -F, -ane'
  BEGIN { $" = "," }
  $. >1 or next;
  $h{"@F[0,2]"}++;
  END { print $k =~ s|,\K| $v,|r while ($k,$v) = each(%h)  }
' file
```

with sorting,

```
perl -F, -ane'
  BEGIN { $" = "," }
  $. >1 or next;
  $h{"@F[0,2]"}++;
  END { print s|,\K| $h{$_},|r for sort {$h{$b} <=> $h{$a}} keys %h  }
' file
```

Comment: Btw, is available RAM important issue? `:)`

Comment: `++$h{"@F[0,2]"} if $. > 1`?

Comment: Yes, that is shorter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command line

```
cat FileName | awk -F, '{print $1, $3}' | sort | uniq -c
```

If the file is too big and unwieldy, it can be split up using one of the fields, like so:

```
awk -F, '{gsub(" ", "_", $3); print $0 >> $3; close($3); }' FileName
```

I chose 3rd field assuming number of organizations is relatively small compared to number of domains. This command replaces spaces with '_' in the file name. After getting counts from the smaller files, they can be combined easily.

EDIT: The relative performance of solutions depends on the ratio:

```
number of unique keys (combinations of organization and domain) / Total number of lines in the file
```

If this ratio is very small, counting using a hash table performs better and uses less memory. If the ratio is large, sorting would be better.

Comment: `sort` on a 300M line input stream is going to take a while

Comment: I tried to solve problems like these with maintaining a running count with a hash table and using Unix sort. In my experience, the solution using sort command almost always outperforms the one using hash table approach.

Answer (score 0):

data.csv

```
domain,ip,org
emileaben.com, 94.31.44.1, Level 3 Communications
anaplan.com, 94.31.44.12, Level 3 Communications
anaplan.com, 94.31.44.15, abc
anaplan.com, 94.31.44.19, Level 3 Communications
```

count.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $results = {};
while (<>) {
    next if $. == 1; # Skip Header
    chomp;
    my ($domain, $ip, $org) = split /,\s*/;
    $results->{$domain}->{$org}->{$ip} = 1;  # Ignore duplicates
}

print "domain,ip,org\n";
for my $domain (sort keys %$results) {
    for my $org (sort keys %{ $results->{$domain} }) {
        my $ips_per_domain = scalar keys %{ $results->{$domain}->{$org} };
        print join(', ', $domain, $ips_per_domain, $org) . "\n";
    }
}
```

cat data.csv | count.pl

```
domain,ip,org
anaplan.com, 2, Level 3 Communications
anaplan.com, 1, abc
emileaben.com, 1, Level 3 Communications
```

Comment: Tough to avoid, but depending on the number of duplicate rows, this could eat a *lot* of memory for a 300 million+ row file (at least 10s of GB according to my [conservative] back-of-the-napkin estimate).

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different solution that might take longer in complete processing time, but is more memory safe. It works by first grouping the input file by organization then computing ip counts based on these smaller "org" files:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper; 
use feature qw/say/;

my %fhs_by_organization;
while ( my $row = <> ) {
    next if $. == 1; # Skip Header
    chomp($row);

    my ($domain, $ip, $org) = split(/,\s*/, $row);
    unless ( exists $fhs_by_organization{$org} ) {
       my $outfilename = join('_', split(/\s+/, $org)) . '.txt';
       open my $fh, '>', $outfilename
          or die "$!";
       $fhs_by_organization{$org} = $fh;
    }
    say { $fhs_by_organization{$org} } "$domain, $ip";
}

# close resources
close($_) foreach values %fhs_by_organization;

# read each org file in separately to reduce memory load
my %ipcount_by_org_domain;
foreach my $org ( keys %fhs_by_organization ) {
    if ( fork() == 0 ) { # child code 
       my $infilename = join('_', split(/\s+/, $org)) . '.txt';
       open my $fh, '<', $infilename
          or die "$!";

       my %seen_domainips;
       while ( my $org_row = <$fh> ) {
          my ($domain, $ip) = split /,\s*/, $org_row;

          # only count unique ips 
          next if $seen_domainips{$domain . $ip};

          $ipcount_by_org_domain{$org}->{$domain}++;
          $seen_domainips{$domain . $ip} = 1;
       }
       close $fh;
       unlink $infilename;
       exit;
    }
}

# wait for all of the child processes to finish
wait for 0 .. scalar keys %fhs_by_organization;

# dump results
$Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;
print Dumper \%ipcount_by_org_domain;
```

Also: organizations are unique, so you can use fork to process them in parallel. Processing a 3.5m line file on my machine took ~19 seconds.

outputs:

```
{
  'Level 3 Communications' => {
                                'emileaben.com' => 1,
                                'anaplan.com' => 2
                              },
  'abc' => {
             'anaplan.com' => 1
           }
}
```

Comment: Certainly safer than the other solutions in terms of memory usage, but depending on the number of unique organizations, could easily hit the limit on open file descriptors (on my machine, 98422 for the entire system, or 4096 for a single process).

Comment: yeah, good point . Same thing could follow from fork()ing too many processes, one per org.